# MongoDB beginner - Group by date

Tags: mongodb

Just starting with mongodb and used this post to do a similar query but I need the actual date like mm/dd/yyyy instead of just the day of year - help!

[How to group by multiple fields in MongoDB when one is a date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170243/how-to-group-by-multiple-fields-in-mongodb-when-one-is-a-date-field)

Here is the query I have (almost the same as the post above):

```
db.col.aggregate(
    { $group: { 
        _id: { 
            status: "$status", 
            dayOfYear: { $dayOfYear: "$datetime" }
        },
        hits: { $sum: "$hits" } 
    } }
)
```

Here is sample data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("45f5ed29f4e1a522bfe53f13"),
    "hits" : 2,
    "status" : 400,
    "datetime" : ISODate("2014-01-10T10:17:57.216Z")
}
```

Comment: Can you write what you have exactly right now so we can fix it ;)

Comment: Posted the query I have - thanks!

Comment: Sample data helps ;). Give me a min...

Comment: @user3210860 MongoDB isn't well-equipped for string operations. Why don't you convert the day-of-year to the correct date on the application layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more date columns or remove them to get different groupings:

```
db.col.aggregate(
    { $group: { 
        _id: { 
            status: "$status", 
            month: { $month: "$datetime" },
            day: { $dayOfYear: "$datetime" },
            year: { $year: "$datetime" }
        },
        hits: { $sum: "$hits" } 
    } }
)
```

What this means is: for each unique status that appeared on a particular day (ignore time) sum up all hits.