# MongoDB - multiple groupings in a hystorical session

Tags: mongodb, redash

I work with MongoDB on Redash as a way to easily create and analyze reports, graphs and such. I have created a graph that describes the last 12 months of transactions, grouped by month. But now I also need to group these transactions within each month by gateway. I'm currently using a $project followed by a $group stages, as such:

```
        {
            "$project": {
                "nominal": {
                    "$divide": [
                        "$amount",
                        100
                    ]
                },
                "month": {
                    "$month": "$created_at"
                }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$month",
                "total": {
                    "$sum": "$nominal"
                }
            }
        }
```

The resulting table is a very simple month-to-value relation.
What I need is a way to separate the quantities within each month by gateway, similar to an SQL line of the sort:

```
SELECT [...], sum(amount OVER (PARTITION BY gateway) FROM [...] GROUP BY month, gateway ORDER BY total, month, gateway
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group by multiple fields in MongoDB when one is a date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170243/how-to-group-by-multiple-fields-in-mongodb-when-one-is-a-date-field)

Comment: You just have to modify the `_id` key in your `$group` stage to include the additional `transactions` key. Something like this: `"_id": {"month": "$month", "transaction": "$transaction"},`